# Coloring compiler diagnostics with SCons

Tags: python, gcc, build, scons, terminal-color

I am currently using the [colorama](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) package to color messages generated by my build scripts. I have also used [scolorizer](https://github.com/icebreaker/scolorizer), which replaces the build commands with custom, colored messages using `strfunction()` in SCons. This sure makes build output less verbose and warnings easier to spot.

However, I often prefer to see the full command lines when building. Is there a mechanism in [SCons](http://www.scons.org) to capture compiler output, giving the opportunity to inject some terminal colors before printing it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting CC and CXX in the environment to a suitable wrapper around your compiler, for example [colorgcc](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html).

Comment: yup. my favourite. it can be quite tricky to get SCons to use that, though. SCons has philosophy of trying to be environment-isolated

Comment: hmm yes, I might get it to work also in Windows using `Win32::Console::ANSI`. +1

Comment: scons + colorgcc is officially explained here : http://www.scons.org/wiki/ColorGcc