# Colorizing GCC Messages Outputted by Existing Builtin SCons Builders

Tags: gcc, colors, terminal, builder, scons

Is it possible to inject some logic into the existing SCons Builders for, in my case, C,C++ and Fortran to colorize *GCC compiler* warnings, infos, errors similar to what is done at

https://github.com/icebreaker/scolorizer/blob/master/colorizer.py

Comment: Just use a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) -e.g. 4.9 or better- it accepts the [-fdiagnostics-color](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Language-Independent-Options.html#Language-Independent-Options) option

Comment: I'm aware of this. However, upgrading the compiler is currently not possible in our project. I just want to know if there is some point in SCons where I can inject filtering on GCC compiler output.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7628881/1158895